# Does Func<T> callbacks can cause memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, closures

Everybody know that eventhandlers that are never removed for the invocationList can cause memory leak in C#. 
My questions is, Can we have memory leak if we use Func as callback? (therefore supporting only one subscriber)

Take the following example (copy and paste into console application):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new Manager();

        var c1 = new Channel();
        m.Add(c1);
        Console.WriteLine("m = {0}",GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

        Console.ReadLine();

        m.Remove(c1);
        Console.WriteLine("m = {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Manager
{

    List<Channel> channels = new List<Channel>();

    public void Add(Channel c)
    {

        channels.Add(c);

        c.OnTick = OnTick;

        c.Start();
    }

    public void Remove(Channel c)
    {
        channels.Remove(c);
        //do we have a memory leak at this point?
        //does c1 still pointing to Manager func and cannot be GCed?
        c.Stop();
    }

    private Task OnTick(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public class Channel
{
    public Func<int, Task> OnTick;
    Random r = new Random();
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    public Channel()
    {
        OnTick = i => Task.FromResult(r.Next());
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => OnTick(r.Next());

        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        aTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //do we have a memory leak at this point?

No. Tested this on ANTS Memory Profiler to verify that.

> //does c1 still pointing to Manager func and cannot be GCed?

`Manager` is the subscriber and `Channel` is the publisher. If there are are no reference to the Channel instance and it's eligible GC.